# scp command does not work from process builder in java

Tags: java, authentication, scp, processbuilder, private-key

I have been facing a strange issue in running scp command via my java application.

I am supposed to run this scp command with "-i" option where in ,I pass the identify key of a low privileged user(for an instance user B) while my java process is run by another logged in user(for an instance user A).

This is how my command looks in the application log when it's run by the logged in user "user A".

**scp -l 10000 -o BatchMode=yes -o LogLevel=DEBUG -i "PathToIdentitykeyOfuserB" remoteUser@remoteHost:"PathToRemoteFile" "localPathofCopiedFile"**

This command fails in my java application with errors saying
**stdErr: Warning: Identity file   not accessible: No such file or** directory.
**stdErr: remoteUser@remoteHost: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).**

what makes me wondering is the very same command runs perfectly, when it is run either in cygwin command line or windows command line.

I later added "-o LogLevel=DEBUG" in order to debug the internal logging for scp command to ascertain any difference in the logging  informations of scp command itself (when it was run in windows cmd line) and when it is run via process builder of java application.

I observed that while SCP's(run through user A in windows command line)internal logging says it takes in the very same identity key of user B but its not this case when scp is run via process builder in my java application. Internal debug logging of SCP shows that  it attempts to authenticate using the default private key of user A even after explicitly passing the identity key of user B.

Please find below few screenshots.

**Identity key loaded in the SCP's internal logging from Windows CMD.**

[image]

**Authentication successful via Window CMD**

[image]

**Identity Key loaded in SCP's internal logging from process builder of java Application.**

[image]

[image]

I fail to understand as to why SCP does not attempt to authenticate with the explicitly passed identity key of user B  but rather tries to authenticate with its default identity key(user A).

However, its evident from the attached screenshots that from windows command line, it authenticates with the explicitly passed identity key and as a result, authentication succeeds.

I request experts to help me out with some tips to resolve this problem.

How can I make the process builder to take into account the identity key of passed identity key of another user instead of default key of user initiating it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is how, I was creating process builder.

[image]

[image]

I have created a list of strings which basically holds scp command constructed with the list of strings and then pass this list directly as a parameter to command method of process builder.

Comment: The most common reason for this is incorrectly trying to use shell features in the ProcessBuilder command.

Comment: Given this hint please show how exactly you are calling the ProcessBuilder constructor or any additional command you call before starting/executing the scp command.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your java code for constructing the command and invoking it. It would be helpful to see the actual command being run and the actual value of things like "PathToIdentitykeyOfuserB".

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help and  responses. I have managed to solve it now by creating a temporary file and then writing scp commands to it and run this temporary file in the process builder as against running scp command directly in the process builder earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve it now by creating a temporary file and then writing scp commands to it and run this temporary file in the process builder as against running scp command directly in the process builder earlier.

Instead of passing the list of strings which was used to construct scp command and passing the same to process builder, I have resorted to creating a temporary file and then writing scp command to it and lastly running this temporary file by passing to java process builder.

This solution seems to work now for me.

Comment: Your original code did not work because you are adding two arguments in one line `commandList.add("-o BatchMode=yes")`  => add as "-o" and "BatchMode=yes"